# Sorting Key in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, lambda

I have a list of lists as `myList = [['a',1],['b',4],['a',5], ['b',6]]`.I want to sort this list alphabetically with first element as the key which I can do as `myList.sort(key=lambda x:x[0])` which changes myList to `[['a', 1], ['a', 5], ['b', 4], ['b',6]]`. But if the first elements of the inner lists are the same, I want to sort it in descending order of the second element of the inner list and get the result as `[['a', 5], ['a', 1], ['b', 6], ['b',4]]`. What is the cleaner way to do it? I could have done this in Javascript as

```js
myList.sort((a,b) => {
    if(a[0] == b[0]){
        return b[1] > a[1]
    } else {
        return b[0] < a[0]
    }
})
```

How do I achieve this in python?

Comment: But `[...['b', 4], ['b', 6]]` is not following what you mentioned. It should be `[...['b', 6], ['b', 4]]`, right?

Comment: The answer is in the documentation: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting Hint: probably best to use a lambda function for readability

Comment: `myList.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0],-x[1]))` should do it

Comment: @hygull Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I wanted it to be `[...['b', 6], ['b', 4]]` Edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a tuple as a key:

```
myList.sort(key=lambda x:(x[0], -x[1]))

# myList = [['a', 5], ['a', 1], ['b', 6], ['b', 4]]
```

Comment: The key is a lambda function that returns a tuple of the ordering. First the leftmost element is compared; if they're equal, the second, and so on. `-` makes the sort descending instead of ascending for a particular "column" of numbers.